# Does null conditional operator return false if null?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, c#-6.0, null-coalescing-operator

I have this conditional

`if (item?.Value2?.GetType() != typeof(string) && item.get_Value() == 0)`

I believe that if item is null the `?.` operation will return null, which I believe will be resolved as `false` causing the condition to short circuit and all will be well (`item.get_Value()` won't be called)

However I am not certain, I thought maybe I need to do it like so

`if (item?.Value2?.GetType() ?? 0 != typeof(string) && item.get_Value() == 0)`

but I think that might be overkill, is the first way safe from potential null reference exception?

Comment: There's no need for "belief" in programming. You can always fire up the compiler and test it.

Comment: is item a single cell Excel Range? Do you want to check if the cell value is 0 or if the displayed formatted text is "0" ? It is overkill and is missing a lot of edge cases.

Comment: Why not just 1. [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and/or 2. Try it out and see for yourself?

Comment: There is a lot of very clear information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`item?.Value2?.GetType()` will return `null` if `item` is `null` or `Value2` is `null`.

The condition evaluated will be

```
if (null != typeof(string) && item.get_Value() == 0)
```

so the first condition will be resolved as `true` causing a `NullReferenceException` when `item.get_Value() == 0` will be executed (but only when `item` is `null`, and not `Value2`)

Comment: @RufusL `null != typeof(string)` will evaluate to `true`

Comment: @hellyale it depends, what is the return value of `get_Value()`?

Comment: @hellyale yes if `item` is `null` then `item?.get_value()` will return `null` and the expression `item?.get_Value() ==0` will evaluete to `false`

Answer (score 1):

`.Value2` is faster, but for cells formatted as Date or Currency, `.Value2` returns Double, but `.Value` or `.get_Value()` return DateTime and Decimal. Both result in Double if the cell is numeric type, and String if the value is not numeric type or number formatted as text. The return type can also be Boolean for TRUE and FALSE, and Integer for errors.

---

```
if (0.0.Equals(item.Value2)) // if (item.Value2 is Double && (Double)(item.Value2) == 0.0)
```

This might look strange, but it is the shortest and safest way to check if the run-time [type is Double and equal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,1840cabec71ddb69) to 0.0. (item is not null if it is the result of enumerating a Range)

---

As for the actual problem, to find the first 0 cell:

```
Range cell = range.Find(0, LookAt: XlLookAt.xlWhole);
if (cell != null) { /* ... */ }
```